# How to set 2 bool columns to always only have 1 as true in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, normalization

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    transaction_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    account_id INT NOT NULL,
    transaction_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(),
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

2 quick questions,
first how would I go about allowing only isOutgoing / isIngoing to be TRUE, but not both TRUE? like I could make a trigger but am confused on the logic because how would I know which one is ment to be TRUE?, or should i just make a trigger to throw an error? Not sure on the best way to go about this.

second question, could i normalize this table further potentially?

Comment: Just make one a computed column that's the inverse of the noncomputed column.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
alter table transactions add constraint in_out_check 
check (
  not(isOutgoing = true and isIngoing = true)
);
```

About normalization, if your `description`s are predefined, maybe it would be usefull to create a lookup table for `description`s and replace the `description` column on `transaction` table by the `id` of the lookup.

Comment: the description arnt pre-defined they are optional so should i just keep my table how it is and would this we a 3NF table? Also thanks for the answer to my first question, what would this actually be doing? will it throw an error if i tried to set both to true, or would it send a message? thank you.

Comment: Constraints violated always return an error. About normalization, with just one table of your model I cannot tell you much more. If answer is valid please mark it as correct.

Comment: thank you, is it generally fine to throw errors in MySQL? or is this bad practise

Comment: Also i tried the check command and it doesnt seem to work, apprently it isnt supported in mysql?

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, it works well. You can test on this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=395562833e14dfc18784697ecd3a5aaf